# ROS package wxpropgrid

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody has an idea of how to install the package  wxpropgrid in groovy or if I need to treat it as an external library. And, how to manipulate the manifest and CmakeLists.txt files in case it must be treated as an external library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63928/ros-package-wxpropgrid/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wrapped version of [wxpropgrid](http://www.ros.org/wiki/wxpropgrid) seems to have been last released in Electric.

You will need to treat it as a system dependency.  And add a rosdep dependency to your manifest.  And make sure there's a [rosdep definition for it.](http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2013-05-30**:
Hi, in advance thank you for your answer. However, would you mind giving me a more precise example of the things you are suggesting to do. I mean, How can I treat it as a system dependency, how do I add  rosdep dependency in the manifest and how can I be sure there is a rosdep. In advance, thank you

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-31**:
The manifest is documented here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest